# I want to push a selected value into a select/option dropdown

Tags: javascript, html-select

I want to select a value in a select/option dropdown using javascript only.

**Revised**
sorry for confusion. Here is revised code.

```
document.getElementById("sel_activity").value = activity;
```

This will also work, but is a bit longer..

```
<select id='sel_activity'>
<option value='CYC'>Cycle Count</option>
<option value='INV'>Inventory Count</option>
<option value='INVDROP'>Inventory Drop off</option>
<option value='INVPICK'>Inventory Pick up</option>
<option value='TRAIN'>Training</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

var select = 'CYC';
var myselect=document.getElementById("sel_activity")
for (var i=0; i<myselect.options.length; i++){
 if (myselect.options[i].value == select)
 {
    myselect.options[i].selected = true;
 }
 else
 {
    myselect.options[i].selected = false;
 } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Your question (if there is even one here) doesn't make it clear enough what exactly you're trying to do, which has led to several answers being posted that don't help you.  You should try and add more detail to your post to avoid further confusion or even having the question closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myselect=document.getElementById("sel_activity")
myselect.options[myselect.options.length]=new Option("text","value");
```

http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.3/reference/option.html

Comment: Sorry I did not mean add a new option, but change the displayed option.

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
$("#sel_activity").val("CYC")
```

jQuery is a lightweight javasscript library which is very helpful in DOm traveral,event handling and ajax intearactions.

http://jquery.com/

Adding jQuery to your page is simple as adding one line of code in the head section to include the jQuery library

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="h ttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: My clients include blackberry devices which don't work well with most JS libarries.

Comment: the jQuery library is made of only javascript.You said you need to do this in javascript.

Comment: true indeed, but much more javascript than I want to be loading 
a mobile device. Also BB before OS5.o have unresolved compatibility 
issues with jquery.  Hopefully the jQuery Mobile project will address these.
http://jquerymobile.com/